# Globalize3 multiple locale form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, globalize2

I have a problem regarding submitting multiple locale translations for model data within the same form. For example:

Post model:

```
translates :title
```

How can I post in the 'new' action view which contains the form so that I can submit my title in both :en locale and :fr locale for example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at https://github.com/alvarezrilla/batch_translations

On Rails 3 and globalize3 I had to change a few things for it to work properly. Change all globalize_translations methods to simply translations, remove the proc.binding params to @template.concat and add to your model

```
has_many :translations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations
```

But it's all working.

Your form should look something like this:

```
  <%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @category %>
  <table class="zebra">
    <tbody>
      <%= f.globalize_fields_for(:fr) do |g| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= t(:language).humanize %>: <%= t(:french).humanize %></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= g.label :name, t(:name).humanize %><br/>
            <%= g.text_field :name %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= g.label :description, t(:description).humanize %><br/>
            <%= g.text_area :description, :rows => 40, :cols => 100, :class => "mceEditor" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.globalize_fields_for(:en) do |g| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= t(:language).humanize %>: <%= t(:english).humanize %></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= g.label :name, t(:name).humanize %><br/>
            <%= g.text_field :name %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= g.label :description, t(:description).humanize %><br/>
            <%= g.text_area :description, :rows => 40, :cols => 100, :class => "mceEditor" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit :class=>'button' %> <%= yield :actions %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you have more problems, I'll commit a working version of this for Rails 3.

Comment: I keep getting ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into Hash) on the globalize_fields_for function in the view. Any ideas?

Comment: > http://github.com/alvarezrilla/batch_translations This is now hosted in http://github.com/rilla/batch_translations